# перегрузка оператора ввода

Tags: c#

Как можно реализовать нижеуказанный код на C#. Пример кода на C++:

```
// перегруженный оператор ввода, для ввода значений массива с клавиатуры

istream &operator>> (istream & input, Array &obj)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < obj.size; ix++)
        input >> obj.ptr[ix]; // заполняем массив объекта obj
    return input; // позволяет множественный ввод, типа cin >> x >> y >> z >> ...
}
```

Comment: А с чем у вас затруднения?

Comment: Я  просто хотел вводить значения массива с клавиатуры сразу я нашел метод на С++ не не мог сделать на С#

Comment: Почему бы не "находить и не думать", а "почитать и сделать" ? Синтаксис для перегрузки бинарного оператора такой `public static возвращаемый_тип operator op(тип_параметра1 операнд1,
тип_параметра2 операнд2)
{
// операции
}` ..... всё

Comment: Я сделал. Но немножко кревой. Например с++ что бы перегружать оператор оператор ввода пищется  >>, а в C# не знаю вместо этого что написать. ReadLine что ли?

Comment: _в C# нет оператора вывода, есть оператор сдвига с заранее определенными параметрами: первый параметр - объект класса или структуры содержащей оператор, второй - целое число_: [Определенные пользователем типы могут вызвать перегрузку оператора `<<` (см.оператор); тип первого операнда **должен быть** определен пользователем, а тип второго **должен быть** `int`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator)

Comment: Прямо — никак, в C# нет `istream`. И идиоматический ввод не происходит при помощи оператора `<<`, так что вы не сможете ввести произвольный тип при помощи `<<`. Расскажите лучше, какую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @VladD разве нельзя отнаследовать от консоли (если она не Sealed) и добавить оператор `>>` в него? Ну или создать свой класс, в котором консоль передать как параметр?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: `static class Console`

Comment: @Grundy ммм. ну это усложняет задачу, но не делает невыполнимой))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, отнаследоваться нельзя :-) оператор `<<` как уже писалось выше должен иметь два параметра с жесткими типами, то есть его будет проблематично (читай невозможно) использовать в том смысле как указано в вопрос в примере на C++

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, самое близкое, что можно придумать, сделать метод расширения наподобие такого:

```
public static TextReader Input(this TextReader input, string[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        arr[i] = input.ReadLine();

    return input;
}
```

Теперь можно писать так:

```
var arr1 = new string[3];
var arr2 = new string[2];

using (var reader = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
{
    // Множественный ввод
    reader.Input(arr1).Input(arr2);
}

// Ввод из консоли
Console.In.Input(arr1);
```

При желании, можно сделать `Split` вводимых строк по пробелу и пр.